# In webots 2019a, how to use Supervisor to reset the physical world with Python?

Tags: webots

Recently, I am training a robot to go on itself with Reinforcement Learning in webots 2019a. However, I cannot figure out how to reset the world with Supervisor in Python. Thus I have to click the RESET button everytime it fails.
So, how to use a Supervisor to reset the world?

In official doc @ https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab=python
@func: resetPhysics is as follows:

class Node:
        def resetPhysics(self):
        # ...

However, the previous part of the doc is talking about Supervisor node.
I don't know how to use it. Can anyone give an example on it?
I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Webots R2019a, a supervisor is simply a [Robot](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) node which has its `supervisor` field set to `TRUE`. Therefore, to use a supervisor to reset the physical world, you need to add a Robot node in your simulation (or turn your existing Robot into a supervisor by setting its `supervisor` field to `TRUE`). Once done, this robot can use the [Supervisor API](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab=python).
There are different ways to reset the physics of a simulation, partially or totally. A simple search for the "reset" keyword on [this page](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab=python) will list them all. However, I guess the one you want to use is [`simulationReset()`](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab=python#wb_supervisor_simulation_reset), as it does the same as the RESET button of the user interface.